# how to connect to mysql with visual basic 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i am very beginner in visual basic and i have 2010 express. i want to connect to mysql located on my website's server in visual basic. i downloaded mysql connector, but i dont know anything about how to use it in vb.

i appreciate for any help or any direction...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial that may be useful for you: http://www.linglom.com/2009/02/12/accessing-mysql-on-vbnet-using-mysql-connectornet-part-i-introduction/

Comment: great tutorial but i can not find MYSQL.data in visual basic references :(

Comment: Have you installed the connector (http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/06/accessing-mysql-on-vbnet-using-mysql-connectornet-part-v-install-mysql-connector-net/) and added the reference (http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/13/accessing-mysql-on-vbnet-using-mysql-connectornet-part-vi-create-connection/)?